# Updating vertices Z in polyline from points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, editing

I'm trying to snap a line's vertices to several points in height. The XY have already been snaped, but the snap tool doesn't seem to get the Z value. There is one vertex for each point. Is there a way to update the vertices of the line with the Z value of the points?

[image: Z of points and polyline.]

I've had a similar [problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251481/updating-z-values-from-joined-table-using-arcpy) before, but that time it was between points which shared the same ID. I'm not sure the vertices are able to store an ID the same way. I have acces to Arcgis Pro 2.2 and ArcMap 10.6.

Update: I tried to edit BERAs code to edit an existing fc instead of creating a new one.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(existingFC, ['SHAPE@']) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    linelist = []
    for part in row[0]: 
        partlist = []
        for pnt in part:
            if (pnt.X, pnt.Y) in pointzdict:
                print("in list")
                row[0] = arcpy.Point(pnt.X,pnt.Y,pointzdict[(pnt.X,pnt.Y)])
            else:
                row[0] = pnt
    #row[0] = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array(linelist), arcpy.Describe(polylinefc2).spatialReference, True)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
SystemError: <built-in method updateRow of da.UpdateCursor object at 0x00000195B48ECDF0> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use arcpy. Create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with Point XY as key and Z as value using the da.SearchCursor. Then use da.UpdateCursor to update Z values of line vertices found in the dictionary:

```py
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Default.gdb' #Change
polylinefc = 'polylineZ' #Change to input line name, have to be in workspace
pointfc = 'pointZ' #Change to input Point name, have to be in workspace

pointzdict = {k:v for k,v in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pointfc,['SHAPE@XY','SHAPE@Z'])} #Create dictionary of points with XY as key and Z as values

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(polylinefc,'SHAPE@') as cursor: #Update Z of polyline vertices where a match is found in point dictionary
    for row in cursor:
        linelist = []
        for part in row[0]:
            partlist=[]
            for pnt in part:
                if (pnt.X,pnt.Y) in pointzdict:
                    partlist.append(arcpy.Point(pnt.X,pnt.Y,pointzdict[(pnt.X,pnt.Y)]))
                else:
                    partlist.append(pnt)
            linelist.append(partlist)
        row[0] = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array(linelist), arcpy.Describe(polylinefc).spatialReference, True)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]